# transforming with xsl an xml schema template to an other xml schema template

Tags: xslt, xsd

can anyone give me a paradigm of transforming an xml schema template like

```
    <xs:element name="carareWrap">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The CARARE wrapper element. It wraps CARARE elements.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="carare"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

to an other xml schema template with xsl?
the other xml schema could be anything you can do.. I just need to have somwthing to start with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can anyone give me a paradigm of transforming an xml schema template like ... to an other xml schema template?

An XML Schema is just a an XML document with declared namespace uri `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. Therefore, you can apply XSLT as usual.

For instance, you have a source schema like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="carareWrap">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The CARARE wrapper element. It wraps CARARE elements.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="carare"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And (for example) you want to remove the attributes of reference elements only. You can apply the following transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:element[@ref]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@ref"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will be:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="carareWrap">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The CARARE wrapper element. It wraps CARARE elements.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="carare" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**Notice**

- The needing of the declaration of the namespace of the input document in the XSLT
- The usage of the identity transform to copy the input document as is and override the elements as by requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about trating XSD documents. They are just XML.

Since you do not specify *what* changes you want to make, here is a sample XSLT stylesheet that changes a random detail (the value of `minOccurs` in this case)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <!-- the identity template copyies everything as-is -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ...unless there is a more specific template available -->
  <xsl:template match="
    xs:element[@name = 'carareWrap']//xs:element[@ref = 'carare' and @minOccurs = 1]/@minOccurs
  ">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">2</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="carareWrap">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The CARARE wrapper element. It wraps CARARE elements.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="carare"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A few things to notice:

- the namespace declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` so the `xs` prefix is available in the XSLT stylesheet
- the use of the identity template copy everything that is not handled otherwise
- the use of a complex match expression to pick a specific node
- the use of an *attribute value template* and the `name()` function to copy the attribute name: `name="{name()}"`