# XSLT to transform XSD to another XSD with minOccurs tags

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have an existing XSD with a series of complex types defined in it.  I need to build a correlary XSD for each of these types but every element in each of the complex types needs to be optional (minOccurs = "0").

I found this posting as an example to start from ... but I'm not able to add the optional tag.
[transforming with xsl an xml schema template to an other xml schema template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341829/transforming-with-xsl-an-xml-schema-template-to-an-other-xml-schema-template)

Any help from someone who is more versed with XSLT than I?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested very much since you provided no sample but following stylesheet based on [Identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) could make a job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- Identity transform - copy everything into output -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- for not-root xs:element ... -->
    <xsl:template match="xs:element[ancestor::xs:complexType]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- ... add minOccurs element ...-->
            <xsl:attribute name="minOccurs">0</xsl:attribute>
            <!-- ... and copy everything but not minOccurs attribute if any -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*[not(name() = 'minOccurs')]" />     
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1. You might use an `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` before the `<xsl:attribute>` though. This way the `@*[not(name() = 'minOccurs')]` is no longer necessary - an attribute specified twice will overwrite the previous one.